# How do I run a single test with Nose in Pylons

Tags: testing, pylons, nose, nosetests

I have a Pylons 1.0 app with a bunch of tests in the test/functional directory.
I'm getting weird test results and I want to just run a single test. 
The nose documentation says I should be able to pass in a test name at the command line but I get ImportErrors no matter what I do

For example:

```
nosetests -x -s sometestname
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/tsq/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/loader.py", line 371, in loadTestsFromName
   module = resolve_name(addr.module)
  File "/home/ben/.virtualenvs/tsq/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose-0.11.4-py2.6.egg/nose/util.py", line 334, in resolve_name
   module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: No module named sometestname
```

I get the same error for

```
nosetests -x -s appname.tests.functional.testcontroller
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

`nosetests appname.tests.functional.test_controller` should work, where the file is named `test_controller.py`.

To run a specific test class and method use a path of the form `module.path:ClassNameInFile.method_name`, that is, with a colon separating the module/file path and the objects within the file. `module.path` is the relative path to the file (e.g. `tests/my_tests.py:ClassNameInFile.method_name`).

Comment: Ahhh, the one combination I didn't try. *sigh*. Thanks!

Comment: That will run every test in a test controller/module. What about running a single test method? Something like `appname.tests.functional.test_controller.name_of_test_method`.

Comment: To run a specific test class and method use a path of the form `module.path:ClassNameInFile.method_name`, that is, with a colon separating the module/file path and the objects within the file.

Comment: For anyone else confused: `module.path` is the relative path to the file (e.g. `my_tests.py:ClassNameInFile.method_name`), not the path you would use in an `import` statement

Comment: @bcoughlan I added this to the answer! This was really confusing.

Comment: How do I do this from within python? If I try `nose.run('my_tests.py:ClassNameInFile.method_name')` I get the error: `ImportError: No module named py:ClassNameInFile.method_name`.

If I use `nose.run(argv=['my_tests.py:ClassNameInFile.method_name'])` then it runs all tests, not just `method_name`.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I figured it out. The trick is to prepend `nosetests` as an argument. `nose.run(argv=['nosetests','sample_test.py:TestLambda.test_cylp'])`

Comment: It would be worth adding that for calling parameterized tests (the ones that use @parameterized.expand) you have to use this syntax: my_tests.py:ClassNameInFile.method_name_testnumber, where testnumber is 1, 2, 3, ... one per parametrized test

Answer (score 47):

For me using Nosetests 1.3.0 these variants are working (but make sure you have `__init__.py` in your tests folder):

```
nosetests [options] tests.ui_tests
nosetests [options] tests/ui_tests.py
nosetests [options] tests.ui_tests:TestUI.test_admin_page
```

Note that single colon between module name and class name.

Comment: Thanks for the second option, with the help of bash autocomplete definitely the most convenient one.

Comment: It would be worth note that for calling parameterized tests (the ones that use @parameterized.expand) you have to use this syntax: test_file.py:ClassNameInFile.MethodName_TestNumber, where TestNumber could be 1, 2, 3, ... one per parametrized test

Answer (score 2):

I have to add the ".py" file extension, that is,

```
r'/path_to/my_file.py:' +  r'test_func_xy'
```

Maybe this is because I don't have any classes in the file. 
Without the `.py`, nose was complaining:

> Can't find callable test_func_xy in file /path_to/my_file: file is not
>   a python module

And this although I have an `__init__.py` in the folder `/path_to/`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small script, based on the previous answers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# 
# Usage:
# 
#     ./noseTest <filename> <method_name>
# 
# e.g.:
# 
#     ./noseTest test/MainTest.py mergeAll
#     
# It is assumed that the file and the test class have the _same name_ 
# (e.g. the test class `MainTest` is defined in the file `MainTest.py`).
# If you don't follow this convention, this script won't work for you.
#

testFile="$1"
testMethod="$2"

testClass="$(basename "$testFile" .py)"

nosetests "$testFile:$testClass.test_$testMethod"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me just well:

```
nosetests test_file.py:method_name
```

Note that my tests where not in a class. Test methods were in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

For nosetests `1.3.7`, you need to do:

`nosetests --tests=tests.test_something.py,tests.test_something_else.py`.