# How to specify which tests to run with "python setup.py nosetests"

Tags: python, nose

Behold, my setup.py:

https://github.com/mongodb/motor/blob/master/setup.py

... and setup.cfg:

https://github.com/mongodb/motor/blob/master/setup.cfg

I'd like to be able to run one suite, like:

```
python setup.py nosetests test.test_motor_ssl
```

But I get "invalid command name 'test.test_motor_ssl'". With this, on the other hand:

```
python setup.py nosetests --tests test.test_motor_ssl
```

... nosetests runs every test in my project. How can I tell nosetests, **when it is running in setup.py**, how to run a subset of tests?

Comment: Would one of these posts/links have what you are looking for?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704473/how-do-i-run-a-single-test-with-nose-in-pylons    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210519/manually-adding-test-suite-to-nose/13996879#13996879    http://blog.cesarcd.com/2011/11/python-testing-with-nose-by-example.html  Cheers

Comment: No, because those posts/links don't answer the question in the way I asked it, specifically highlighted in bold: They don't tell me how to run one test suite when nose is running in setup.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug in nose 1.2.1 and they already have a fix in the master branch. You can either wait for the next version or use the `nosetests` command directly.

source: https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/556

Comment: Just that it is not fixed yet also in the 1.3.X version

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that works now is actually the directory approach. It is still not possible to specify the path...

```
python setup.py nosetests -w tests/test_folder
```

Answer (score 3):

Using nose==1.3.1 I'm able to run a single test class/test case via:
`python setup.py nosetests --tests tests/test_file.py:TestClass.test_case`